# jQtouch webapp behaving working fine on mac Safari but won't work on iPhone Safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, web-applications, mobile, jqtouch

This is my first web app and I developed this one by following Jonathan Stark's Building iphone apps with HTML, css and javascript. Everything was testing ok on my mac safari, even when I select Develop > User Agent > Mobile Safari... You can view the above site in your safari and see it's working fine.

However when I finally (thought I had) finished everything and view stuffs from my iPhone safari, the whole world collapsed... Things are so messed up.

I'm using jQtouch and I somehow get an idea that it might because I'm pulling data from JSON files... Because if I pull data from the local storage (like favorites and combination), it's working fine without any issue. However if it's pulling data from JSON, then it'll turn into a mess...

My JSON file is located here:

http://hongteetrading.com/demos/pronouncecn/lib/names.json

The javascript used for pulling data:

$.getJSON("lib/names.json",function(data) {

```
    $.each(data.names,function(i,val){
          if(val.spelling==id){ ... }
```

I guess there could be any better ways of doing it? Or what kind of data-interchange formate you're using with jQtouch?

Answer (score 0):

There are few errors in your HTML that you should fix before you do anything else. Use the W3C service to review them:

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhongteetrading.com%2Fdemos%2Fpronouncecn%2F%23home

Once those errors are fixed you will have a better chance of hunting down the specific things that are rendering differently between devices because you'll be conforming to standards.

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing it out! I've cleared all the error messages however it's still not working on my iPhone.

Comment: Which version of the iphone do you have, which version of safari does it run? I put it through the Apple SDK iPhone simulator and it all seems to be working as expected (a very cool idea and execution, btw). I wonder if perhaps there is a feature included that's supported in Safari but not in Safari for iPhone.

Comment: I have an iPhone 4 and I've also got an iPhone Simulator installed on my mac, and neither worked. On my iPhone 4 it just keeps giving me the wrong letter. On the iPhone Simulator it even gives me blank pages after I click a letter. I've edited my question with more details. Many thanks again.

Comment: Your JSON itself is valid, so probably not the cause. Could it possibly be related to this bug? http://yekmer.posterous.com/how-to-fix-jqtouch-blank-black-screen-problem You're definitely using statically-named elements in there so it might be worth investigating.